# Java: Dependency Injection on foreign-constructed objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm a huge fan of D.I.
I'm currently developing a not-so-small project which uses D.I. everywhere
*(classic and beautiful D.I. **by hand**).*

From my point of view there are following advantages:

- It's **intuitive** when you got used to it,
- doesn't affect **readability** in negative way
  *(in fact, it gets even better)*,
- but the most important thing is: if I want to **test** parts or whole project
  with different implementations of some interfaces, I can do it by changing
  **few characters**, instead of doing complex refactoring/renaming or other workarounds.

But, sadly, I can't figure out, how D.I. can be used with foreign-created
objects in an elegant way (without some frameworks, remember,
I do D.I. by hand).

D.I. by hand means: you **pass something to a c-tor**.
No global factories or similar, God forbid!

JAXB, for example, creates objects by itself. There is no way
to tell the JAXBContext: "please, use following parameters to create my
objects". JAXB only accepts parameterless c-tors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Why does "D.I. by hand" have to mean "pass something to a c-tor"?

Could you do this?

```
ThingOne one = new ThingOne();
one.setInjectedItem( a );
one.setOtherInjectedItem( b );
```

In spring dependency injection, this would be injection via a property and I don't see why this can't be done "by hand."

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't the JAXBContext use a [factory method](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/apidocs/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)) anyway? You can pass parameters into this like you would a constructor. If that doesn't do what you want, traditional setter injection (i.e. calling `context.setXyz(xyzInstance)` methods) after creating your object would emulate by hand what spring et al do automatically...

Comment: +1 I would go with either of the ones suggested. @ivan if you are still not comfortable with the lines of code that would call it, wrap them and move that code elsewhere. Its a restriction and you have to deal with it at some point. I also don't know if java allows, but in .net you can call the constructor of the already instantiated object through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

People have been known to use [getter injection](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/crazybob/archive/2004/05/getterbased_dep.html) to do this. I wouldn't know how to do this in a luddite DI environment.